# C# odd object behavior

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, reference

I noticed something in C# when dealing with custom objects that I found to be a little odd. I am certain it is just a lack of understanding on my part so maybe someone can enlighten me.

If I create a custom object and then I assign that object to the property of another object and the second object modifies the object assigned to it, those changes are reflected in the same class that did the assigning even though nothing is returned.

You want that in English? Here is an example:

```
class MyProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myList = new List<string>();
        myList.Add("I was added from MyProgram.Main().");
        var myObject = new SomeObject();
        myObject.MyList = myList;
        myObject.DoSomething();

        foreach (string s in myList)
            Console.WriteLine(s); // This displays both strings.
    }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.MyList.Add("I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()");
    }
}
```

In the above sample I would have thought that, because `SomeObject.DoSomething()` returns void, this program would only display `"I was added from MyProgram.Main()."`. However, the `List<string>` in fact contains both that line and `"I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()"`.

Here is another example. In this example the string remains unchanged. What is the difference and what am I missing?

```
class MyProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myString = "I was set in MyProgram.Main()";
        var myObject = new SomeObject();
        myObject.MyString = myString;
        myObject.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine(myString); // Displays original string.
    }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.MyString = "I was set in SomeObject.DoSomething().";
    }
}
```

This program sample ends up displaying `"I was set in MyProgram.Main()"`. After seeing the results of the first sample I would have assumed that the second program would have overwritten the string with `"I was set in SomeObject.DoSomething()."`. I think I must be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't odd, or strange. When you create a class, you create reference type. When you pass references to objects around, modifications to the objects they refer to are visible to anyone that holds a reference to that object.

```
var myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("I was added from MyProgram.Main().");
var myObject = new SomeObject();
myObject.MyList = myList;
myObject.DoSomething();
```

So in this block of code, you instantiate a new instance of `List<string>` and assign a reference to that instance to the variable `myList`. Then you add `"I was added from MyProgram.Main()."` to the list referred to by `myList`. Then you assign a refernce to that same list to `myObject.MyList` (to be explicit, both `myList` and `myObject.MyList` are referring to the same `List<string>`! Then you invoke `myObject.DoSomething()` which adds `"I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()"` to `myObject.MyList`. Since both `myList` and `myObject.MyList` are referring to the same `List<string>`, they will both see this modification.

Let's go by way of analogy. I have a piece of paper with a telephone number on it. I photocopy that piece of paper and give it to you. We both have a piece of paper with the same telephone number on it. Now I call up that number and tell the person on the other end of the line to put a banner up on their house that says `"I was added from MyProgram.Main()."` You call up the person on the other end of the line to put a banner up on their house that says `"I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()"`. Well, the person who lives at the house that has that telephone number is now going to have two banners outside their house. One that says

```
I was added from MyProgram.Main().
```

and another that says

```
I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()
```

Make sense?

Now, in your second example, it's a little trickier.

```
var myString = "I was set in MyProgram.Main()";
var myObject = new SomeObject();
myObject.MyString = myString;
myObject.DoSomething();
```

You start by creating a new `string` whose value is `"I was set in MyProgram.Main()"` and assign a reference to that string to `myString`. Then you assign a reference to that same string to `myObject.MyString`. Again, both `myString` and `myObject.MyString` are referring to that same `string` whose value is `"I was set in MyProgram.Main()"`. But then you invoke `myObject.DoSomething` which has this interesting line

```
this.MyString = "I was set in SomeObject.DoSomething().";
```

Well, now you've created a new `string` whose value is `"I was set in SomeObject.DoSomething()."` and assign a reference to that `string` to `myObject.MyString`. Note that you never changed the reference that `myString` holds. So now, `myString` and `myObject.MyString` are referring to different strings!

Let's go by analogy again. I have a piece of paper with a web address on it. I photocopy that piece of paper and give it to you. We both have a piece of paper with the same web address on it. You cross out that web address and write down a different address. It doesn't affect what I see on my piece of paper!

Finally, a lot of people in this thread are yammering about the immutability of `string`. What is going on here has nothing to do with the immutability of `string`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the clearest and easiest to understand answer so far. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: That makes sense. So if `DoSomething()` did `this.MyList = new List<string> { "Added from SomeObject" };` then I would be creating a new object to which `Main()` has no reference.

Comment: @Alex Ford: That's exactly right. In that case `myList` and myObject.MyList` are not referring to different instances of `List<string>`.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. I can't help but think that string immutabiity has its word in here. Not in THIS concrete example, but if SomeObject.DoSomething's code was this : `this.MyString += "I was updated in SomeObject.DoSomething().";` , then you would have to explain that new String is created by the "concatenation", and the first string is not updated

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely correct:

```
myObject.MyList = myList;
```

This line assign a reference of `myList` to the myObject's property.
To prove this this, call `GetHashCode()` on `myList` and on  `myObject.MyList`.

we are talking about different pointers to same memory location, if you wish.

Comment: "You will see that hashcode is equal, which means that we are talking about exactly the same object." Not correct.

Comment: "To prove this this, call `GetHashCode()` on `myList` and on `myObject.MyList`." This doesn't prove anything, except that they have the same hash code.

Comment: @Jason: in case if it's not overwritten, it proves that you're talking about the same "object" (memory location), call it how you want.

Comment: @Tigran: No, it doesn't prove that. Here: `class Foo { public override int GetHashCode() { return 17; } public override bool Equals(object obj) { return Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj); } }`. Now `var first = new Foo(); var second = new Foo();` Now `first` and `second` have the same hash code but refer to different objects.

Comment: @Jason: pay attention on what I write: "in case if it's not overwritten". You overwrite! In question we are talking about List<T> BCL artifact, which is not overwrittent, so has it's default behaviour.

Comment: I understand. ReferenceEquals is basically ==. The point here was to SHOW, so PROVE to a guy that having the same ID, the changes made on  these objects properties/fields will affect each other.

Comment: "`ReferenceEquals` is basically `==`." No, `Object.ReferenceEquals` is reference equality. `==` could be overridden. "having the same ID" hash code is not an object id.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a method returns something, has nothing to do with what happens inside it.
You seem to be confused regarding what assignment actually means.

Let's start from the beginning.

```
var myList = new List<string>();
```

allocates a new `List<string>` object in memory and puts a **reference** to it into `myList` variable.
There is currently just one instance of `List<string>` created by your code but you can store  *references* to it in different places.

```
var theSameList = myList; 
var sameOldList = myList;
someObject.MyList = myList;
```

Right now `myList`, `theSameList`, `sameOldList` and `someObject.MyList` (which is in turn stored in a private field of `SomeObject` automagically generated by compiler) **all refer to the same object**.

Have a look at these:

```
var bob = new Person();
var guyIMetInTheBar = bob;
alice.Daddy = bob;
harry.Uncle = bob;
itDepartment.Head = bob;
```

There is just one instance of `Person`, and many references to it.
It's only natural that if our Bob grew a year older, each instance's `Age` would have increased.
It's the same object.

If a city was renamed, you'd expect all maps to be re-printed with its new name.

You find it strange that

> those changes are reflected in the same class that did the assigning

—but wait, changes are not *reflected*. There's no copying under the hood. They're just there, because it's the same object, and if you change it, wherever you access it from, you access its current state.

So it matters not **where** you add an item to the list: **as long as you're referring to the same list, you'll see the item being added.**

As for your second example, I see Jason has already provided you with a [much better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560861/c-odd-object-behavior/7560929#7560929) than I could possibly deliver so I won't go into that.

It will suffice if I say:

1. Strings are immutable in .NET, you can't modify an instance of `string` for a variety of reasons.
2. Even if they were mutable (like `List<T>` that has its internal state modifiable via methods), in your second example, **you're not changing the object, you're changing the reference**.

   ```
   var goodGuy = jack;
   alice.Lover = jack;
   alice.Lover = mike;
   ```

Would `alice`'s change of mood make `jack` a bad guy? Certainly not.
Similarly, changing `myObject.MyString` doesn't affect local variable `myString`. You don't do anything to the string itself (and in fact, you can't).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing both type of objects.
A List is a List of type string .. which means it can take strings :)

When you call the Add method it adds the string literal to its collection of strings.

At the time you call your DoSomething() method, the same list reference is available to it as the one you had in Main. Hence you could see both strings when you printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, that your variables are objects too.  In the first example, you create a List<> object and assign it to your new object. You only hold a reference to a list, in this case, you now hold two references to the same list.

In the second example you assign a specific string object to your instance.

Comment: well yeah ok, variables are variables :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how reference types behave and is expected. myList and myObject.MyList are *references* to the same List object in heap memory.

In the second example strings are immutable and are passed by value, so on the line

```
myObject.MyString = myString;
```

The contents of myString are *copied* to myObject.MyString (i.e. passed by *value* not by *reference*)

String is a bit special because it is a reference type and a value type with the special property of immutability (once you have created a string you can't change it only make a new one, but this is somewhat hidden from you by the implementation)

Comment: "The contents of myString are copied to `myObject.MyString` (i.e. passed by value not by reference)" This is completely wrong. `String` are reference type; just because they are immutable doesn't change the fundamental fact that they are reference types. Also, what is happening here has nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: "Well, now you've created a new string whose value is "I was set in SomeObject.DoSomething()." from your answer, now if that's not immutability at work I don't what is.

Comment: Take the first example, and instead of the body `this.MyList.Add("I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()");` in `DoSomething`, change the body to `this.MyList = new List<string> { "I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()" };` and now the behavior is that `myList` only contains `"I was added from MyProgram.Main()."` and `myObject.MyList` contains `"I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()"` That is what is happening in the `string` example.  Note that `List<string>` are mutable. This has nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: Ok but now you're being explicit with the "new" keyword. I would argue strings are reference types "under-the-hood" but the semantics are always strings are passed by value behaving like value types (I am only talking .NET here). Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Alex - you wrote -

> In the above sample I would have thought that, because SomeObject.DoSomething() returns void, this program would only display "I was added from MyProgram.Main().". However, the List in fact contains both that line and "I was added from SomeObject.DoSomething()".

This is not the case.  The VOID of the function just means the function does not return a value.  This has nothing to do with the this.MyList.Add method you are invoking in the DoSomething() method. You do have to references to the same object - myList and the MyList in the SomeObject.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example ... you are working with an mutable objects, and it is always accessed by reerence. **All references to MyList in different objects refer to the same thing**.

In the other case, strings behave a bit differently. Declaring a string literal (i.e. text between quotes) creates a new instance of a String, completely separated from the original version. **You CAN NOT modify a string, just create a new one**.

**UPDATE**

**Jason is right**, it has nothing to do with String immutability ... but ....
I can't help but think that string immutabiity has its word in here. Not in THIS concrete example, but if `SomeObject.DoSomething`'s code was this : `this.MyString += "I was updated in SomeObject.DoSomething().";` , then you would have to explain that new String is created by the "concatenation", and the first string is not updated

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability of `string`.